# Reading X and Y coordinates of text file into array list

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, arraylist

I am trying to change this array to an arrayList. It reads the x and y coordinates of two points for a line and the color of the line. Later I will be using a equals() method to determine if two lines are equal and only add the first one. For now I am just trying to and the file into the arrayList. If i use just the array Line[]lines, the program runs fine, but when I run it like this, using the arrayList, it just a blank panel which is what the second loop is for leading to there is nothing in the arrayList.

My Text file looks like this:

```
3   
482 22 335 492 red  
482 22 335 492 blue  
482 22 335 492 green

//Line[] lines;
ArrayList<Line> lines;
Scanner reader;

int numLines = reader.nextInt();
    //lines = new Line[numLines];
    ArrayList<Line>lines = new ArrayList<Line>();

while( reader.hasNext() ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < numLines; i++ ) {
            int x = reader.nextInt();
            int y = reader.nextInt();
            Point beg = new Point(x,y);
            x = reader.nextInt();
            y = reader.nextInt();
            Point end = new Point(x,y);

            String color = reader.next();

            Line l =  new Line( beg, end, color );
            lines.add(l); 
            //lines[i] = l;
```

Using this loop I am trying to add each line to the arrayList

```
if( lines != null ) {
        for( Line l: lines ) {
            int x1 = l.getBeg().getX();
            int y1 = l.getBeg().getY();
            int x2 = l.getEnd().getX();
            int y2 = l.getEnd().getY();

            g.setColor(l.color);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            System.out.println(l);
```

This is the paint component, if the list is empty leaves the panel blank.

My question is am I using the first loop right or is there something I need to do for it to work with the arrayList?

Comment: It looks okay to me, the only thing the concerns me is you have defined `lines` as a local variable in the reading portion of the code, but the `lines` array must have being defined with a class instance...

Comment: Yes I've been looking over it and researching but can't find anything but like this it displays a blank panel. If I simply just comment out the arrayList, and uncomment the array and lines[i] = l it displays the green line which is why i was thinking something is wrong with my loop

Comment: You actually define the `lines` ArrayList twice...

Comment: Sounds like you are shadowing your variables.  The `ArrayList` lines is declared locally to the read method, this would suggest that the `lines` in the paint method is not the same you used to read the data into...Instead of `ArrayList<Line>lines = new ArrayList<Line>();`, try `lines = new ArrayList<Line>();`

Answer (score 1):

Without further context, you appear to be shadowing your variables...

You start out with these declarations, which "appear" to instance variables...

```
//Line[] lines;
ArrayList<Line> lines;
Scanner reader;
```

But when you initalise them, you do this...

```
int numLines = reader.nextInt();
//lines = new Line[numLines];
ArrayList<Line>lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
// Warning bells, redeclaration of lines!!
```

This would "suggest" that you are shadowing your variables, meaning that your paint the method is using the reference to `lines` that you declared at a class level.

Instead, you should be initialising your variables more like...

```
int numLines = reader.nextInt();
//lines = new Line[numLines];
lines = new ArrayList<Line>(numLines);
```

nb. Use the `numLines` to initialise the `ArrayList`, it will be more efficient...